# How to use rxjs map to dig into a HttpClient get request response?

Tags: angular

I'm setting up an Angular service that does a get request to SWAPI.
I want to map the response to subscribe only to the part I am interested in (in my case: the planets).

The problem is rather simple: I have the error "TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'".

Does someone know what I don´t get here?

Thanks a lot!

```
export class PlanetsService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  allPlanets(): Observable<Planet[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
      .pipe(
        map(res => res.results)
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should subscribe to the observable returned by `allPlanets` to actually have the request sent. After that, I suggest you to remove the map operator for a while and log the result from the request using subscribe to check how it looks like and if it really has a `results` property.

Comment: Thanks! It does have a results property. I think mbojko found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generics. Even something like

```
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl)
```